# mod_evasive doesn't work

Tags: php, apache, ddos, mod-evasive

mod_evasive is install and my config is

```
<IfModule mod_evasive20.c> 
    DOSHashTableSize    3097 
    DOSPageCount        2 
    DOSSiteCount        50 
    DOSPageInterval     1 
    DOSSiteInterval     1 
    DOSBlockingPeriod   50 
</IfModule>
```

Now i go to some page and refresh it about 11 times and it shows 403 error but then after 1 sec i refresh the page i see the page content not the error i mean by using this

```
DOSBlockingPeriod   50
```

the error should stay for 50 sec right ?

Comment: It should be blocked for 50 seconds, yes. Did you check Apache's logs?

Comment: duplicate of http://serverfault.com/questions/423553/mod-evasive-not-working-properly-on-ubuntu-10-04